# Специфичный прогресс бар

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сверстать подобный прогресс бар?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```js
// Для демонстрации
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  var fill = $('.bar_fill');
  var size = parseInt($(this).attr('data-fill'));
  fill.css('width', size + '%');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.bar_scale {
  height: 30px;
  background: #8ea1b3;
  position: relative;
}

.bar_fill {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  background: rgb(110, 175, 253);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(110, 175, 253, 1) 0%, rgba(56, 100, 247, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(110, 175, 253, 1) 0%, rgba(56, 100, 247, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(110, 175, 253, 1) 0%, rgba(56, 100, 247, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6eaffd', endColorstr='#3864f7', GradientType=1);
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}

.bar_overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent 10px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 10px);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, transparent 10px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 10px);
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 10px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 10px);
  background-size: 16px 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar">
  <div class="bar_scale">
    <div class="bar_fill" style="width:60%;"></div>
    <div class="bar_overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<button class="btn" data-fill="0">0%</button>
<button class="btn" data-fill="25">25%</button>
<button class="btn" data-fill="50">50%</button>
<button class="btn" data-fill="75">75%</button>
<button class="btn" data-fill="100">100%</button>
```